# React passing arrow function as props to component. Cannot read property 'purchaseAd' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a function purchaseAs as a props to a component but I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'purchaseAd' of undefined. What am I doing wrong? Apologies, I know this is a frequently asked question however I am new to React.

```
class Seller extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var data = require('./sellerData.json');
        this.state = {
            sellerData: data
        };
     }


purchaseAd = () =>
{
    console.log("called")

}

render () {
    return (
      <Layout>
      {
        this.state.sellerData.map(function(advertiser) 
        {
        return (
            <Entry
            purchaseAd = {this.purchaseAd}
            key = {advertiser.id}
            advertiser = {advertiser}
            /> 
            )
          }
      )}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `this.state.sellerData.map(function(advertiser)`

When you use a non arrow function here, the value of `this` changes when that function is invoked. Convert that to an arrow function like this: `this.state.sellerData.map((advertiser) =>` and you should be all set

Comment: @ChrisJohnston I'd highly recommend reading the first two chapters of [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes), was extremely useful for me understanding how `this` works

Comment: And honestly, everything else in that book series is great as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an arrow function to pass the scope of **this** inside your map function.

```
this.state.sellerData.map((advertiser) => {
your code...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, other answer was 1 minute before yours so I accepted his. apologies